# The variable answer is being used without being initialized?

Tags: c++

Any help?
When I put the two numbers in, it says answer is not being initialized...?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int num;
  int num2;
  int working;
  int answer;
  int uChoice;
  int work( int one, int two, int todo );
  cout << "Welcome to my Basic Mini-Calculator!" << endl;
  do
    {
      cout << endl << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
      cout << "1) Add" << endl;
      cout << "2) Subtract" << endl;
      cout << "3) Multiply" << endl;
      cout << "4) Divide" << endl;
      cout << endl << "Waiting for input... (enter a number): ";
      cin >> uChoice;
      cout << endl;

    } while( uChoice != 1 && uChoice != 2 && uChoice != 3 && uChoice != 4 );

  switch ( uChoice )
    {
    case 1:
      cout << endl << "You chose addition." << endl;
      cout << "Enter a number: ";
      cin >> num;
      cout << "Enter another number: ";
      cin >> num2;
      working = num + num2;
      cout << "Your answer is: " << answer;
      break;

    case 2:
      cout << endl << "You chose subtraction." << endl;
      cout << "Enter a number: ";
      cin >> num;
      cout << "Enter another number: ";
      cin >> num2;
      working = num - num2;
      cout << "Your answer is: " << answer;
      break;

    case 3:
      cout << endl << "You chose multiplication." << endl;
      cout << "Enter a number: ";
      cin >> num;
      cout << "Enter another number: ";
      cin >> num2;
      working = num * num2;
      cout << "Your answer is: " << answer;
      break;

    case 4:
      cout << endl << "You chose division." << endl;
      cout << "Enter a number: ";
      cin >> num;
      cout << "Enter another number: ";
      cin >> num2;
      working = num / num2;
      cout << "Your answer is: " << answer;
      break;
      return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably mean "working" rather than "answer"...

Comment: Your code never assigns to the `answer` variable before printing its value. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

It is exactly that. You declare answer:

```
int answer;
```

then you use it many times without initializing it or assigning any values to it:

```
cout << "Your answer is: " << answer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `answer` without ever assigning a value to it, just like the warning states :-)

It's possible that the statement sections like:

```
working = num + num2;
cout << "Your answer is: " << answer;
```

should actually have:

```
answer = num + num2;
```

instead.

In that case, you can probably get rid of `working` altogether.